# Google meta description uses <noscript> instead of JS content

Tags: javascript, html, seo, meta-tags

On our page we have a `<noscript>` inside the `<body>` at top and via JavaScript we define the title and meta description of the page, as we want it to be dynamic.

However, on google search results the page appears with a random title of the page content and the description shows with the `<noscript>` content which is basically a message saying to activate JavaScript.

How can this be resolved? Is a static meta description required?

Comment: An example of what the code looks like would help. Sounds like Google is having trouble executing your JavaScript. What does it look like in the Mobile Friendly Test tool?